# How to automatically center an absolute element inside a relative parent with CSS only?

Tags: css, css-position, centering

I saw that there were some posts on the subject but none of them answers my question specifically

http://jsfiddle.net/27van/ shows how to center text horizontally.

I want to center it vertically in the parent `div`, without using the `top` which sets a fixed number of pixels (while I need it to be dynamic)

Any clues?

```css
.parent_div {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.child_div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_div">
  <img src=...></img>
  <div class="child_div">
    <h1>Some Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your code look like? All we can provide are general solutions at this point

Comment: Edited the question to add what i tried!

Comment: So what exactly do you want to center vertically? The h1?

Comment: I want to center the child_div. If i add more text, if i add an image as well, i want it always to be in the center of the parent_div.

Answer (score 9):

Because you have given the child element a width of 100% so i am guessing you are looking to center align it vertically ... in that case you need to know the height of your `.child-div` if it has a fixed height then you can use something like this:

`.parent_div {
  position: relative;
}`

```
.child-div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px; /* for example */
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px /* height divided by 2 */
}
```

and if the height is unknown then you can use the same method but calculate height & margin via jQuery. And just in case you wanted to align it horizontally you can use the same method but with these changes ... in this case you need fixed width.

```
.child-div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px; /* for example */
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -50px /* width divided by 2 */
    }
```

Your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27van/1/)

Comment: you could also use `calc()` instead of negative margin: `left: calc(50%-100px);`